# c# Converting part of form into a child

Tags: c#, visual-studio, mdi, mdichild

I have a Visual Studio (15,19) C# form with several grouped fields (in GroupBoxes).
I wish to convert some such groups into mainform's children, accessed by menuestrip.
I can easily make the main form into parnet and add menuestrip items, but I don't know if there is a simple way to **convert a whole group into a child**.
For example, I have in the main form a group that sets serial port's parameters: Port, boud, parity, etc. and I wish to move the group out of the main form and make it a form's child that can be opened by the menuestrip or by command from the main form.

Comment: what do you mean about **a form's child**? Is it a child form from the Main form? Also, it will be better for you to provide some code about your question to describe your question.

Comment: Thx. To make it clear: I have a main form containing items gouped in VS group-boxes.  I wish to convert such group into main form's child in one piece and move it out of the main form's diaplay, without making a new empty child and rebuilding each item in the group.
The question was: Is there a way to move the grpoupbox in one piece out of the main form and make it a functioning child?
(I can cut the group out and and paste into a new child form, but this will only move the controls, not its logic)
The code it far too complex and big to show.

Comment: Do you want to the child form inside the main form? Like the [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFDW9.png

Comment: Thanks all. Solved the problem by building a new child form, copy-paste the groupbox with all it's items and manually rebuilding the program items associated with the controls.
I encounted a new problem for which I will start a new thread. (unable to display the child form on top of all main form controls)